# Creating widgets for dashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, dashing

I`m trying to create a widget for dashing (http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) for displaying 4 values:

value1
value2
value3
value4

I have copied the contents of the text widget and added the following to the widget.html

```
<h3 data-bind="text | raw"></h3>

<p class="more-info" data-bind="moreinfo | raw"></p>
<p class="value1" data-bind="value1"></p>
<p class="value2" data-bind="value2"></p>
<p class="value3" data-bind="value3"></p>
<p class="value4" data-bind="value4"></p>
<p class="updated-at" data-bind="updatedAtMessage"></p>
```

When I add this widget to my dashboard using:

```
      <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="mywidget" data-view="mywidget" data-title="Grupserhs" data-text="Systems Dashboard" data-moreinfo="Hello"></div>
     </li>
```

Yet I have a blank page in my dashboard.

What would be the correct way to create a widget that will only receive pushed data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this? http://shopify.github.io/dashing/#widgets

Comment: Yes. I have read this 10 times, yet I cannot find a way to sedn multiple item values..

Comment: Please post the complete information into gist for reference, .scss/.html/.coffee

Answer (score 1):

Actually use "list" widget for this. Look at the 'buzzwords.rb' file for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a coffeeScript file that defines your widget class and extends Dashing.Widget? You don't need anything else in there to start, but that is where your widget is defined.
Also, do you have a job pushing data to this widget id "mywidget"? If not, look in the jobs folder, same level as widgets folder to get an idea, basically a Rufus scheduler task to pump data to your widgets. ..and don't forget to check the css for your widget..

Answer (score 0):

From the current information, in the dashboard, it shall using like

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="mywidget" data-view="mywidget" data-title="Grupserhs" data-text="Systems Dashboard" data-moreinfo="Hello" data-value1="first value" data-value2="this is value2" data-value3="value3" data-value4="last value" ></div>
</li>
```

The `data-bind="value1"` shall be mapped into dashboard like `data-value1`

It may have other problems, like putting those widget in separate folder, your css format. Please provide more detail file list for reference if it can't solve it.